# Function/Operation Definitions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, binary-operations

If I want to define a function/operation for equivalence classes, is it permissible to stipulate contingencies based upon element characteristics or does dependency on the choice of element characteristics invalidate the definition? A possible example: 
if *b* > *a*, then (*a*,*b*)+(*c*,*d*) = *ab*+*cd* 
and 
if *b* < *a*, then (*a*,*b*)+(*c*,*d*) = *abc*+*d*, etc.

Comment: No, this will (in general) not yield a well-defined function. Also: The first sentence of your post makes my head hurt. That kind of convoluted language isn't in anybody's best interest when communicating about mathematics...

Comment: Your possible example has nothing do to with equivalence realations.

Comment: An example of equivalence classes based upon element characteristics is sets of things with the same color, or classes of sets with the same cardinality.

Comment: Your example is completely valid, it's an example of definition by cases (though the $+$ function here is undefined when $a=b$). However this works because this is not about equivalence classes. I'm not sure what you are trying to do with equivalence classes, depending on it you may or not be able to define functions for them.

Comment: @Ryunaq I'm approaching this backwards because I have been active in coding in imperative languages and have recently been studying functional programming. As I have focused more on the basic construction of integers and rationals, I have wondered about how operations with equivalence classes in those instances have been defined and to what extent other options are possible. I want to know what would determine the boundaries of possibility in this context, what things are off-limits in math that could be easy to do and not throw errors when done in code.

Comment: @bblohowiak Sorry for the late response. As some other commenters point out, are you sure that what you are interested in is *equivalence classes*? If what you care is only "stipulating contingencies", the only off-limit thing you can't do is overdefining. For example: if $x>3$ then $f(x)=10$, if $x<4$ then $f(x)=0$. Here, $f(3.5)=10=0$, which is clearly wrong. That's the only off-limit thing.